# Retag [dragon-quest-7] -> [dragon-quest-vii]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

This looks extremely pedantic, but all but one of the other dragon quest tags involve Roman numerals rather than numbers, so I think we should stick to the pattern. I was actually in the process of editing the tag into [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/295362/162442) but I got ninja'd.

Comment: It could also go the other way and we could retag all the Roman numerals into numbers, but I figured we should keep what we already had ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think it would make sense to conform to the common search query within the Internet. Usually that's by given style, but you do run into those rarities like and FF7 vs FFVIII and FF12 vs FFXIII...Roman Numerals is probably most correct semantically, but... What about using both?

Comment: @ShawnGordon having two tags is what DanmakuGrazer suggested in the linked meta (see my comment on the answer). We can create tag synonyms with the Arabic numerals for games whose titles have Roman numerals in them. I believe this is what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since tags are meant reflect actual usage, and the title of the game is [*Dragon Quest VII*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest_VII) (less the subtitle) in fact and not just styling, yes, the tag should be [dragon-quest-vii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-vii), with a synonym from [dragon-quest-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-7) pointing to it for convenience.

(It's probably *“7”* now just because whoever used the tag first wrote it that way. That doesn't establish any precedent we have to honour, it just indicates that a synonym with that name would be practical.)

Comment: True, but I've noticed we don't always follow the game's official title for tag purposes, namely the Final Fantasy series. But since prior to this tag, the ratio was 4-1 Roman numerals, I figured it would be best to keep it consistent with its own series, at least.

Comment: @Vemonus That's true… I suppose practically, in the case of FF, with so many games it's easier to be sure that the right tag was chosen since they're less likely to mistype Arabic numerals than Roman numerals. On that thought though, it might be worth discussing if we should standardise how to name tags for games with Roman numerals. Using Arabic numerals would seem to be most practical: easier to type accurately and easier to read/understand.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I see benefit in such a discussion, given how many different cases already exist.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer created a meta [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting)